# Junit test for database migration from MySql to Mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, junit

I have set of existing legacy junit test case which runs as expected with rollback support, and also does the CRUD operation with mongo .
The legacy junit has spring rollback support and has annotation defined as

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
```

While running maven command as **mvn clean install** , it creates lot of collection objects .Since I do not see any rollback transaction support associated with mongod , I am ending up creating many documents in mongo which are not needed.

Is there any way I can use rollback in junit for mongod or any anyway I can delete the mongo collection when the project build is over.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use spring-data-mongodb? Or how do you connect to the db?

Comment: We are using mongo java driver .

Comment: Use the database named `test` and call the `drop()` method on your collection object when you are done.

Comment: Thank you for advise , that is very much doable .Like there are 500 legacy test cases so was thinking if there is any way we could let maven handle after the test cases are done to delete the document.